# UI5 Generic Tile with filter functionality

Tags: sapui5

I have Generic Tiles in my UI5 App. My requirement is to implement the functionality of Icon Tab Bar - Filter (https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.m.sample.IconTabBar/preview) for these tiles. I have separate tile for each status and on clicking it should display the list in the table depending on the clicked status eg: 'completed tickets'.
The table and the tiles are in different views. If this is possible please provide suggestions as to how this can be accomplished.

Thanks,
Srinivasan

Answer (score 0):

You could follow the example of the `IconTabBar` almost literally, and just swap the icons for tiles.

When you press an icon in the `IconTabBar` in the example, the logic connected to that icon will add a filter to the binding of the table. You should do the same: the logic connected to your tiles, should also change the filter of the table binding. Every tile could result in a different filter to the binding. With that, you would see the table filtered based on the tiles you clicked.

With your table being in a different view than the tiles, you may want to use the router to communicate between the two views. You could e.g. have tile one to navigate to `/YourApp/#/Stuff/FilterBySomething` and tile two to navigate to `/YourApp/#/Stuff/FilterBySomethingElse`. In the view containing your table, you should then pick up the filter info and add the filter to the table binding accordingly. More info on how this works can be found in [Step 31 of the SAPUI5 walkthough](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/guide/e5200ee755f344c8aef8efcbab3308fb.html).

Comment: Thank you jpenninkhof. I had tried that functionality when my IconTabBar filters and Table were in the same view. But now the table and the tiles are in different views. I am struck here on how to filter the table in that view from here.

Comment: I'm afraid I missed that part @SrinivasanS. I've modified the answer accordingly.

Comment: With your further suggestions I have reached till the below code toDetail: function(oEvent) {
    var oBindContext = oEvent.getSource().getBindingContext();
    var oModel = oBindContext.getModel();
    var oRouter = sap.ui.core.UIComponent.getRouterFor(this);
    var sObjectID = oModel.getData(oBindContext.getPath()).ObjectID;
    oRouter.navTo("srvdetail", {
     ID: sObjectID
    });
  },

Comment: This code when used in table helped me to get the row details and pass to another view. When I used it for the tile I get an error saying "getData is undefined". Hope you could correct me here.